# spring boot cloud sns push notification

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I want to send "mobile push notifications" to ios/android devices using AWS. I am able to do this using the sample provided by Amazon:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePushAPNSAPI.html

However, my current build stack is based on Spring Boot and would prefer to use the Spring Cloud AWS. I see that it currently support pub/sub topic based messaging but doesn't support sending "mobile push notifications".

Am I correct in saying this?

Will Spring Cloud AWS ever support "mobile push notifications" over sns? I'm sure its not hard for Spring to provide this!

My fallback plan is to wrap "amazons sample code" into Spring and use it. Would this be a sensible thing to do?

Hope someone can answer these questions or any samples code they can point to.

Regards
GM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configure the [Spring Cloud AWS Messaging](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_messaging) then you could @Autowire the [AmazonSNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNS.html) in your @Component class.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes this is the only alternative right now. Lets hope that spring guys can add this functionality in in the near future.